# ReactJS i18n library implementation problem

Tags: reactjs, i18next

I am a newbie in React and I'm trying to add i18n in my app. I cannot figure out /I know it is something stupid from my side, but I couldn't find a solution about my problem/. I have two simple questions and I would be very happy if you give me the answer for them.

1. I'm trying to add the resources in my menu component, but it gives me "Parsing error: Unexpected token". Can you please advice me how to add the const about i18n.

   ```
   import React from "react";
   import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
   import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
   import "./navbar.scss";

   const Navbar = () => (
     const { t, i18n } = useTranslation()
     <div className="Navbar">
       <nav>
         <ul>
           <li>
             <Link to="">{t('b.label')}</Link>
           </li>
           <li>
             <Link to="/">{t('sm.label')}</Link>
           </li>
           <li>
             <Link to="/">{t('aboutmenu.label')}</Link>
           </li>
           <li>
             <Link to="/">{t('contactmenu.label')}}</Link>
           </li>
           <li>
             <Link to="/">BG/EN</Link>
           </li>
         </ul>
       </nav>
     </div>
   );
   export default Navbar;
   ```
2. My second question is how to add the internationalisation library to my title tag, because my structure is that  is in an html component.

I know those are very stupid questions but I teach myself to react and I cannot find those simple answers.

Thank you in advance, I promise not to bother you for those kind of questions anymore in the future

Comment: On what line does it crash? You should be able to extract that from the stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are no stupid questions, no worries.

1. Try the following code instead:

```js
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';

import "./navbar.scss";

const Navbar = () => {
  const { t, i18n } = useTranslation();

  return (
    <span>{t('b.label')}</span>
    <span>{t('sm.label')}</span>
    <span>{t('aboutmenu.label')}</span>
    <span>{t('contactmenu.label')}</span>
  );
}
```

2. If you started your project with [create-react-app](https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html#create-react-app) in most cases you shouldn't need to add libraries in your `head` tag (which is located in `public/index.html`). To configure the react-i18next library read the [react-i18next guide](https://react.i18next.com/latest/using-with-hooks#configure-i-18-next).

This seems like a good [youtube guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cHqxgLhOl5Y) that should teach you more about react and i18n-react. Good luck! :)